# First non-repeated character

Tags: c++, performance, strings, c++11, programming-challenge

Challenge description is [here](https://www.codeeval.com/open_challenges/12/) need to find the first non repeated character from the string:

> Write a program which finds the first non-repeated character in a string.
>
> **Input sample:**
>
> The first argument is a path to a file. The file contains strings.
>
> For example:
>
> ```
> yellow
> tooth
> ```
>
> **Output sample:**
>
> Print to stdout the first non-repeated character, one per line.
>
> For example:
>
> ```
> y
> t
> ```

Please let me know can I improve my solution.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <map>
#include <cstring>

 
void findNonRepeatedChar( const std::string& record)
{
    auto pred= [&record] ( char a, char b){ 
                  return strchr( record.c_str(), a ) < strchr( record.c_str(), b ); 
                };
    std::map< char, int, decltype(pred) > stringMap(pred);
    for( auto elem : record )
    {
        auto it = stringMap.find( elem );
        if( it != std::end(stringMap) )
        {
            ++(it->second);
        }
        else
        {
            stringMap.insert( std::make_pair<char&,int>(elem, 1));
        }
    }
    for( auto elem : stringMap)
    {
        if(elem.second == 1)
        {
            std::cout<< elem.first << "\n";
            break;
        }
    }
}

void readInputFile( const char * fileName )
{
    std::ifstream inFile( fileName, std::ifstream::in );
    std::string record="tooth";
    
    if( !inFile.is_open())
    {
        std::cout<<"File open failed \n";
        return;
    }
    while( getline( inFile, record ) )
    {
        findNonRepeatedChar(record);
    }
}

int main( int argc, char* argv[] )
{
    if( argc < 2 )
    {
        std::cout<<"Usage:program_name input_file_name \n";
    }
    readInputFile(argv[1]);
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've reviewed your code and here's what I've found.

### Reconsider your algorithm

It's not really necessary to iterate through all of the characters in the string, as the current code does.  Since the task is to find only the *first* non-repeated character, the algorithm can terminate as soon as it finds a non-repeated character.  A simple way to do that is this:

```
void findNonRepeatedChar( const std::string& record )
{
    for (std::string::size_type i = 0; i < record.size(); ++i) {
        if (record.rfind(record[i]) == i) {
            if (record.find(record[i]) == i) {
                std::cout << record[i] << '\n';
                return;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

### Reconsider the interface

It is odd that a function named `findNonRepeatedChar()` does not actually return anything.  The code could be clearer if it actually returned the non-repeated letter and left the printing to the calling routine.

### Don't instantiate an object that is not needed

There is no reason to instantiate the `record` to `"tooth"` (or any other value) within `readInputFile`.

### Use more descriptive function names

The function named `readInputFile` does more than simply read the file and as mentioned before, the `findNonRepeatedChar()` function doesn't return anything but prints as a side effect.  I'd be inclined to omit `readInputFile` entirely, and put its contents within `main` and to change the interface to as previously mentioned.

### Give the user useful help

The program is probably not really named `program_name` so the string that's printed if there aren't enough commmand line arguments should probably instead be:

```
std::cout << "Usage: " << argv[0] << " input_file_name\n";
```

Answer (score 2):

Your `findNonRepeatedChar` function seems more complex than required. I disagree with the algorithm that @Edward posted, as it makes what should be a linear time solution into a quadratic time solution.

Here is a simpler algorithm:

- Build a map containing characters and the number of times they exist in the string.
- Walk through the string from left to right, looking up the number of times the character appears in the string.

In code, this looks like:

```
char find_first_non_repeat(const std::string& s)
{
    std::unordered_map<char, unsigned> count;
    for(auto c : s) {
        count[c] += 1;
    }
    for(auto c : s) {
        if(count[c] == 1) {
            return c;
        }
    }
    return char(0);
}
```

Here, I've used an `unordered_map`. Generally you should prefer `unordered_map` over `map` unless you absolutely need ordering.

It's easier to use `operator[]` here instead of dealing directly with iterators and comparing to `end` to decide whether to insert or not. For complex objects using `operator[]` can have performance penalties, but for basic types like characters and integers, this isn't a concern.

The interface is also different: it returns a `char` instead of just printing the character. This change might seem unimportant, but actually, it's a pretty big difference in at least one area: testing. Your function, as it stands, is very hard to test in any kind of automatic way. Having it return the value instead makes it easier to test (and also adheres better to the single responsibility principle).

Comment: It's true that the algorithm you propose has a lower complexity, but the savings in time due to the algorithm must be weighed against the time cost of creating and destroying the `unordered_map`.  On my Linux machine, the algorithm I posted takes 214 ms to process `usr/share/dict/words` while the code you posted takes 853 ms.  The original code takes 1218 ms for comparison.

Comment: Most of the time difference can be erased by using `int count[256];` and `memset(count, 0, 256);` instead of the `unordered_map`.

Comment: @Edward Of course, this very much depends on the input data. For a large number of short words, constant factors will dominate. Using `int count[256]` is indeed a reasonable workaround, although I would write this as `int count[256] = {0};` to avoid having the `memset`.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming we are speaking of bytes only.
Not knowing what has to be done if no such character is found.

Here is a simple C version.  No building, minimal scanning.

Let p a pointer to the first char of the string.
Let n be the length of the string.
The function returns the character in an int, or -1 if no such character exist.

```
static int non_repeat(const char* p, size_t n)
{
    const char* l = &p[n];

    while(p < l)
    {
        char c = *p;

        int n; // count the occurrences after the current one
        for(n = 0; (++p < l) && (*p == c); ++n);
        {
        }

        if(n == 0) // no repeat ?
        {
            return c;
        }
    }

    return -1; // nothing has been found
}
```